# AWS Textract not working with Invoices in PDFs. Any advice?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

There is a "Try" feature in AWS Textract page where we can upload Invoices in PDF, JPEG etc. But when I uploaded the PDF it wasn't working. Table's were not being shown, Form (Key-Pair values) were not being shown....nothing. But when I uploaded Invoice in JPEG it was working good. I didn't understand why.

I searched all over the internet but I couldn't find any solution. Some people even never heard of AWS Textract, even though I found its better than Google Document AI.

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure this is not an issue with low quality of the PDF in question? Have you tried different regions?

Comment: @PawelKam, Nope the invoices that I'm trying to use is of High quality text-based pdfs. You can check the Invoice in this link: https://docdro.id/jDSAO5g

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `amazon-textract-textractor` [package](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-textractor) to simplify calling and parsing Amazon Textract. Here is a link on a tutorial on how to use the AnalyzeExpense API. https://aws-samples.github.io/amazon-textract-textractor/notebooks/using_analyze_expense.html

If your pdf is a single-page, you can use the SYNC `.analyze_expense` API like this:

```py
from textractor import Textractor

extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")

document = extractor.analyze_expense(
    file_source="invoice.pdf",
    save_image=True,
)
document.visualize(with_words=False)
```

[image]

If your PDF document is multi-page, you need to use the ASYNC `.start_expense_analysis` API.
You can do it like this:

```py
from textractor import Textractor

extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")

document = extractor.start_expense_analysis(
    file_source="./multipage_invoice.pdf",
    s3_upload_path="<YOUR S3 BUCKET>",
    s3_output_path="<YOUR S3 BUCKET>",
    save_image=True,
)
document.visualize(with_words=False)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into similar issue today when trying out Amazon textract the first time with simple bank statements. Nothing was parsed successfully even though my uploaded pdfs were a lot simpler than the sample documents. After a few attempts, I realized there is a blue notification on the top that asks if I'd like to create S3 bucket to store the uploaded document. After I clicked on yes, AWS created the bucket automatically, and the real processing of the document began. After several seconds, the results came out correctly matching my document.